# vagrant box packaged on mac cann't be init on windows

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

- First of all, I have setted up my whole developing environment on my Mac vagrant environment
- Second, I run `vagrant package` then generated a box named package.box on my Mac stay with the `Vagrantfile`
- Third, I copy the `package.box` to my Windows environment
- Running `vagrant init tolerious package.box` command, then I run `vagrant up`,but I got this error as follows,
  [image]

I have checked the `vagrant global-status` output, there is a valid id displayed in the list. And I also run the command`vagrant box list`, there is also a valid box added successfully. Anyone has ideas about this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question, the reason is something like this:
I packaged my environment on my Mac, and my Mac is 64-bit, but my windows system is 32-bit, so it can't work properly. I must add such lines in my `Vagrantfile`:

`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
     vb.gui = false
     vb.customize [ 'modifyvm', :id,
     "--hwvirtex", "off",
     '--cpus', 1,
     '--memory', 800,
     '--nicpromisc2', 'allow-all']
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
   end`